# Sending sms text message from android emulator to second emulator instance

Tags: android

I am trying to send sms programmatically from one android emulator to another on Mac OSX. I am able to telnet into the first and send a text message to the second with:

```
sms send 5556 test
```

but... I am not able to send an sms from an android application, here is what I am using to test:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

the phoneNumber = 5556 and message = "test". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is your phonenumber here ?

Comment: the phone number I'm using is the emulator port number, 5556

Comment: Check emulator settings, its connection status. Does it show you "No service"?

Comment: I just checked the status in ddms and both emulators are online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up starting the application from the *second* emulator. That is, from 5556 and it successfully sent an sms to the first emulator I started, to 5554. I don't know why it would not send from the first emulator I started. But nonetheless, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the SEND_SMS permission in the Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I even downloaded the big example that everyone points to here on SO and it does not send either:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: Hmm this is weird, i've just tested the two lines you have posted by sending a message from 5554 to 5556 and everything works fine. Are you getting any error output or what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: No, I'm getting no error at all. Just not receiving a text in the other emulator.