# Android Testing: Can I send sms to the emulator number from test method?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I have received some code from another team and started to simple improvement and re-factoring.
The first phase is adding unit test to the project. I need to test functionality of parsing input sms.
Related to above information my question is:
 - Can I send sms to the emulator port from test method? 
I have writen next code but have no received anything ...

```
@Test
public void sendSmsTest() {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("5554", null, getSms("sms1"), null, null);
}

private String getSms(String smsKey) {
    return (String) smsMessages.get(smsKey);
}
```

Thanks.

---

After restarting emulators and IDE I have received next error in console:

> Test running failed: Exception thrown
>   in onCreate() of
>   ComponentInfo{com.example/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started 2 emulator instances and was able to send an SMS from instance to the other, but... I had a problem where it would only send from the second instance I started. Look at this post:

[Sending sms text message from android emulator to second emulator instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521349/sending-sms-text-message-from-android-emulator-to-second-emulator-instance)

Answer (score 6):

Use something like from the host computer

```
$ adb emu sms send 5551234 Hello Android
```

Comment: I am using this way from console, but question is Can I write some code for send sms, like above? Thanks.

Comment: Create a server in your development computer that take requests and translate them to commands like the one above.

Answer (score 5):

To send SMS to a specific emulator:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 emu sms send 5551234 Hello Android
```

Comment: If you are connected to only a single emulator, you can simplify the command as `adb -e emu sms send 5551234 Hello Android` or even leave the -e option for that matter.
;) Just saying Hi Degu.